# php: wanted to replace '\\\/' from string

Tags: php

I wanted to replace en/us with es/es:

```
<?php

$str = array('url'=>'www.domain.com\/data\/en\/us\/data.gif');

$json = json_encode($str);

$str = str_replace('en\/us', 'es\/es', $json);

echo $str;
```

Comment: replace it befor jeson_encode.

Comment: Why did you put backslashes in the original `$str['url']`? And why do you do `json_encode` in first place?

Comment: Yea because the slash are encoded afterward.

Comment: Look at how your string transforms with `json_encode`, either do it before, or use the altered version. https://eval.in/827336

Comment: The url is already json encoded... `\/`. Why do you encode an encoded string?

Comment: @Robert — No, it isn't. That is the syntax of a PHP string literal. The escape characters will be consumed when the PHP parser converts it into an in-memory string.

Comment: @Quentin maybe, but the fact that they're placed on a `/` which doesn't need escaping indicates there's something else that's off here. Maybe OP is thoughtlessly copy-pasting text from somewhere or `\/` is what he's seeing on screen and assumes that's what in the string. It's very unclear to me.

Comment: @Quentin Yes it is, but that's not what is happening here, and he's not escaping a thing.. I'm pointing out that the json_encode on a url will be the same as his current input. `echo json_encode('www.domain.com/data/en/us/data.gif')` = `"www.domain.com\/data\/en\/us\/data.gif"`. So instead of doing str_replace magic and worrying about escaped and double escaped strings, he should be looking at why his input is like that.

Comment: @Robert He's not encoding a string though. He's encoding an array.

Comment: @Doug That does not change anything. He's fixing the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'double escape' the backslash, like so:

```
<?php

$str = array('url'=>'www.domain.com/data/en/us/data.gif');

$json = json_encode($str);

$str = str_replace('en\\/us', 'es\\/es', $json);

echo $str;
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php (section 'Single quoted').

Would be easier to escape the string BEFORE feeding it to json_encode, but I'm assuming this is a test case and the data you want to replace in is already JSON.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a useful format for moving data between systems. Converting data to JSON and then trying to manipulate it without parsing it first is almost always a terrible (overly complicated and error prone) idea.

Do the replacement **before** you convert it to JSON.

```
<?php

function replace_country($value) {
    echo $value;
    echo "\n";
    return str_replace('en\/us', 'es\/es', $value);
}

$str = array('url'=>'www.domain.com\/data\/en\/us\/data.gif');
$str = array_map("replace_country", $str);
$json = json_encode($str);
echo $json;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = array('url'=>'www.domain.com\/data\/en\/us\/data.gif');
$str['url']=str_replace('en\/us', 'es\/es', $str['url']);
$json = json_encode($str);
```

It produce out put as

[image]

It will work for you.